# In Racket's FFI, how do you register a callback that takes a list?

Tags: list, racket, ffi

I need to define a function in Racket's FFI that takes a callback:

```
(define-ffi-definer define-lib (ffi-lib "libLib"))
(define callback
  (_fun [len : _int]
        [elems : (_list i _int)] -> _void))
(define-lib registerCallback
  (_fun callback -> _void)
  #:c-id registerCallback)
```

I want to be able to define `elems` in terms of `len`, that is, so I can write:

```
(registerCallback (lambda (xs) stuff))
```

How is this accomplished?

Furthermore, my code as written gives the error:

```
length: contract violation
  expected: list?
  given: #<cpointer>
```

I presume this is because `elems` can't be listified.  What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up going with the brute force but effective solution of manually creating a wrapper function:

```
(define callback
  (_fun [len : _int]
        [elems : _pointer] -> _void))
(define-lib registerCallback-raw
  (_fun callback -> _void)
  #:c-id registerCallback)
(define (registerCallback callback)
  (registerCallback-raw
    (lambda (len elems)
      (let ((elems (cblock->list elems _int len)))
        (callback elems)))))
```